# Java Paint program shapes rendering order

Tags: java, arraylist, paint

I have an issue with shapes being rendered in a specific order depending on the order of my for:each loops.

```
ArrayList<CircleTool> circles = new ArrayList<CircleTool>();
ArrayList<SquareTool> rectangles = new ArrayList<SquareTool>();
ArrayList<PenTool> plines = new ArrayList<PenTool>();
```

Following is inside the paintComponent method.

```
// draw canvas
    for (CircleTool circle : circles) {
        circle.draw(g);
    }
    for (PenTool pline : plines) {
        pline.draw(g);
    }
    for (SquareTool rectangle : rectangles) {
        rectangle.draw(g);
    }
```

Each of the shapes including the pen lines are stored in their respective ArrayList.

Is there a clear way to make it draw the latest object on top of older ones?
I've tried making a large array list of existing array lists but then realized that its a quite stupid idea that wont solve anything.

Link to the full PaintPanel.java source code:

PaintPanel.java - http://pastebin.com/04geKmaL

Comment: You say you tried with a single array with all your drawable elements inside it? Those look polymorphic, so a single array should do the job.

Comment: Yes, I made a single array, and later check what kind of object is in that array and print it so the print order is the same ass the order it was drawn.